# BusyBox sed REPL (online)?

Tags: web-apps, programming, macos

There is https://sed.js.org/, a GNU `sed` REPL online to test the `sed` command in a browser. BusyBox's implementation of `sed` is heavily simplified, though. Is there an (online) REPL to test with the limited `sed` of BusyBox? I'd also welcome an offline REPL that runs on MacOS.